# How do I set locked cell protection options in Excel with C# and Interop?

Tags: c#, excel, interop, spreadsheet-protection

Here's the background info. I have an app that writes to an excel 2007 .xlsm file and I am using C# and the Excel 12.0 interop object libraries to do it, along with Visual Studio 2010. I am able to change the cell values and formulas, set the font and font style, set the cells to locked or not, etc. The last thing I need to do is to set the protection of the sheet to disallow selection of locked cells.

When I try to call this code, as a test of general sheet protection...

```
((Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ThisWorkbook.Sheets[0]).Protect(Password: protectionPassword, AllowFormattingCells: false);
```

...I get the exception `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC` telling me a COM Exception was unhandled.

Also, the interop Protection object does not give me the option that I mentioned above, although that option is available in excel when I click "Protect Sheet" under the review tab.

So, now my question: How do I protect the desired sheet in Excel with with the option to AllowSelectLockedCells turned off using Excel Interop in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've probably solved this since it was asked, but for the benefit of those (such as me) who stumble upon this from search engines hoping for a solution:

Three points to get this working:

- `_Application.ThisWorkbook` actually refers to the workbook object that contains macros, not the currently-active workbook in an Excel instance. For that you need `_Application.ActiveWorkbook`.
- Excel worksheet indexes begin at 1, not 0.
- To prevent locked cells from being selected (the AllowSelectLockedCells you were looking for) you first set the `EnableSelection` property to `XlEnableSelection.xlUnlockedCells` before locking the sheet.

So the following will do what you need:

```
((Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1]).EnableSelection = Excel.XlEnableSelection.xlUnlockedCells;
((Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1]).Protect(Password: protectionPassword, AllowFormattingCells: false);
```

Comment: I actually never solved this using Excel Interop. Many thanks for the solution.

Comment: EnableSelection is very important